# Getting the exit code of a shell script, in a C program

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, exit-code

I have a shell script which contains the following lines:

```
if [ $elof -eq 1 ];
then exit 3
else if [  $elof -lt 1 ];then
    exit 4
else
    exit 5
fi
fi
```

In my C program I use `popen` to execute the script like this:

```
char command[30];
char script[30];
scanf("%s", command);
strcpy(script, "./myscript.sh ");
strcat(script, command);
FILE * shell;
shell = popen(script, "r");
if(WEXITSTATUS(pclose(shell))==3) {
   //code
}
else if(WEXITSTATUS(pclose(shell))==4){
  //code
}
```

Now, how do I get the exit code of the script? I tried using `WEXITSTATUS`, but it does not work:

```
WEXITSTATUS(pclose(shell))
```

Comment: What you're showing doesn't give enough context.  Please show a full piece of code with the expected and actual output.

Comment: Show more of your C code... btw, you should only use `WEXITSTATUS()` if `WIFEXITED()` evaluates *true*

Comment: I've edited my C code.

Comment: Don't call `pclose(shell)` more than once!

Comment: @melpomene you're right, I forgot that. But if I use `WEXITSTATUS` and print it out to the console, I get 0. But my script only exits with 3, 4 or 5. How is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[After you have closed a stream, you cannot perform any additional operations on it.](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Closing-Streams.html)

You should not call `read` or `write` or even `pclose` after you called `pclose` on a file object!

`pclose` means you are done with the `FILE *` and it will free all underlying data structures ([proof](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/iofclose.c#L85)).

Calling it the second time can yield anything, including `0`.

Your code should look like this:

```
...
int r = pclose(shell);
if(WEXITSTATUS(r)==3)
{
            printf("AAA\n");
}
else if(WEXITSTATUS(r)==4)
{
            printf("BBB\n");
} else {
    printf("Unexpected exit status %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(r));
}
...
```